# Executing multiple query strings using a variable declared at first one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to execute a long dynamic query string based on a xml variable, then I needed to split the string on multiple `varchar` variables, each one containing part of an update in a table inside a cursor.

I will post part of the query:

```
DECLARE @QUERY1 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @QUERY2 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @QUERY3 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @QUERY4 VARCHAR(8000);

DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(8000);

DECLARE @begin INT
DECLARE @totalid INT
DECLARE @groupsize INT
SET @groupsize = 0
SELECT @totalid = MAX(IntegrationId) FROM Integration
set @QUERY1 = N'
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @xml XML 
DECLARE @XMLReceiverID int
DECLARE XMLRowItem CURSOR FOR
SELECT XMLReceiverID,XMLContent FROM XMLReceiver WHERE FlagImportData = 0 and Typology = ''XXXX''
OPEN XMLRowItem
FETCH XMLRowItem INTO @XMLReceiverID,@xml
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0

BEGIN
';
set @QUERY2 = N'
INSERT INTO IntegrationData (XmlReceiverID) 
';
set @QUERY3 = N'
SELECT @XMLReceiverID
';      
--PRINT @QUERY1 + @QUERY2 + @QUERY3
EXEC (@QUERY1 + @QUERY2 + @QUERY3)      
WHILE @groupsize <= @totalid
BEGIN
SET @begin = @groupsize
SET @groupsize = @groupsize + 10
select @cols = 
(select STUFF((SELECT distinct ',',  QUOTENAME(FieldName), ' = ' , CASE WHEN XMLPath IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '(SELECT TOP 1 c.value(''(' + (REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(XMLPath), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(XMLPath)) - 1)))  + ')[1]'',''VARCHAR(50)'') FROM  @xml.nodes(''' + REPLACE(XMLPath,'/' + REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(XMLPath), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(XMLPath)) - 1)), '') + ''') t(c)) ' END 
from IntegracaoOpcaoLayout
where FlagIntegration = 1 
AND XMLPath IS NOT NULL
AND IntegrationId > @begin
AND IntegrationId <= @groupsize
order by QUOTENAME(FieldName) asc

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,''))

set @QUERY2 = N'
UPDATE IntegrationData SET ' + @cols + ' WHERE XmlReceiverID = @XMLReceiverID
';
EXEC (@QUERY2)
--PRINT @QUERY2
END 
set @QUERY4 = N'    
UPDATE XMLReceiver SET FlagIntegration = 1 WHERE XMLReceiverID = @XMLReceiverID AND FlagImportData = 0
FETCH NEXT FROM XMLRowItem into @XMLReceiverID,@xml
END
PRINT @XMLReceiverID
CLOSE XMLRowItem

DEALLOCATE XMLRowItem
COMMIT TRANSACTION
';
EXEC (@QUERY4)
--PRINT @QUERY4
```

If I run this code printing the query strings and execute it all it works fine!

But if I run normally, I get error bellow (about nor declaring the variable declared at first exec statement):

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near '@XMLReceiverID'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@xml".
```

Has anyone a work around or a suggestion?

Here is the query printed:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @xml XML 
DECLARE @XMLReceiverID int
DECLARE XMLRowItem CURSOR FOR
SELECT XMLReceiverID,XMLContent FROM XMLReceiver WHERE FlagImportData = 0 and Typology = 'XXXX'
OPEN XMLRowItem
FETCH XMLRowItem INTO @XMLReceiverID,@xml
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0

BEGIN

INSERT INTO IntegrationData (XmlReceiverID) 

SELECT @XMLReceiverID

UPDATE IntegrationData SET [Field1] = (SELECT TOP 1 c.value('(test1)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') FROM  @xml.nodes('/xmlPath/test1') t(c)) ,
[Field2] = (SELECT TOP 1 c.value('(test2)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') FROM  @xml.nodes('/xmlPath/test2') t(c)) ,
[Field3] = (SELECT TOP 1 c.value('(test3)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') FROM  @xml.nodes('/xmlPath/test3') t(c)) 
UPDATE XMLReceiver SET FlagImportData = 1 WHERE XMLReceiverID = @XMLReceiverID AND FlagImportData = 0
FETCH NEXT FROM XMLRowItem into @XMLReceiverID,@xml
END
PRINT @XMLReceiverID
CLOSE XMLRowItem

DEALLOCATE XMLRowItem
COMMIT
```

Comment: what's the ouput that you get from printing?

Comment: Please, post table DDL, sample data, and expected results, otherwise we can only guess what you actually need. If you really feel your problem can only be solved by using dynamc T-SQL, please, read the following article on the subject, written by Erland Sommarskog:
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html ML

Comment: i posted @bastos.sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is throwing errors is because all of your code is out of scope.

This is your problem.

```
 set @QUERY2 = N'
    UPDATE IntegrationData SET ' + @cols + ' WHERE XmlReceiverID = @XMLReceiverID
    ';
    EXEC (@QUERY2)
    --PRINT @QUERY2
    END 
    set @QUERY4 = N'    
    UPDATE XMLReceiver SET FlagIntegration = 1 WHERE XMLReceiverID = @XMLReceiverID AND FlagImportData = 0
    FETCH NEXT FROM XMLRowItem into @XMLReceiverID,@xml
    END
    PRINT @XMLReceiverID
    CLOSE XMLRowItem

    DEALLOCATE XMLRowItem
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    ';
```

You can see that you reassign @query2 with a statement that requires @XMLReceiverID, but the variable has not been declared for the new @query2 assignment.  The same thing holds for @query 4.  The two variables @XML,@XMLReceiverId are not in the same scope as @Query1.

Essentially, you need to concatenate all statements into a single variable or combine them together into a single execute.

Comment: The problem is I can't concatenate then all because of the max size of a variable. The query becomes longer than 8000. I will need a while to execute multiple updates because the full update is longer than 8000

Comment: can't you change the variable to varchar(max)?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  Can you use VARCHAR(MAX)  (SQL 2005+) instead?

Comment: the varchar(max) has 8000 chars as maxsize

Comment: "The varchar(max) has 8000 chars as maxsize"  -- This is not true.. It holds up to 2 GB of data.

Comment: Executing this command: DECLARE @QUERY1 VARCHAR(8001); i got the error Msg 131, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
The size (8001) given to the type 'varchar' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).

Comment: or there is any system variable to set the maxsize of it? because looking the error it looks true

Comment: You have to use the keyword "MAX".  You cant give the varchar a number.  e.g. DECLARE @Query1 VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: I have already tried it....the query is too long and i get a sql statement error because of the variable dont store the complete statement

Comment: Are you sure the statement is too long or print cant print the entire statement.  These are two very different things.  Print only allows up to 8000 characters.  http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2010/07/breaking-print-character-limit.html

Comment: Well, if i print the full statement and put on new query window, it runs. Then i store it on a variable varchar(max) and run it, i get statement error. I suppose it dont store the full code, or the exec dont execute a long query, i am not sure what is the true problem

Comment: I will make a new test here and i answer you, ok? Anyway, thanks for the suggestion until now

Comment: When you print it and copy that into a new window it is running in a single batch (all in scope). When you break it apart and execute it in pieces, the variables are no longer in scope.  To solve the issue, combine all the variables into a single varchar(max) variable and execute it...   Bottom line is, you need to execute all your dynamic code with a single EXEC statement, as there are dependencies in the latter query on the former query.

Comment: You were right, @AdamHaines...I printed the query and executed it, and no error. After it, i stored it no a varchar(max) variable and it executed successfully. During the concatenation, i put some enter's and it worked. it was getting sql statement because the absence of enter's. Thanks a lot!